# Match the all line until the regex

Tags: regex, perl

I'm using Perl to write a script and have a question regarding to regex.
I need to match the all line **until** the match regex I have...

for example:

```
 (".$variable.".EXAMPLE\\d+)
```

this is the regex that catch the expression in the line, and I want to make changes in it so it will take the the all line before the expression.

I hope I was clear enough :)

thanks!

Comment: Is this a typo? Do you have an extra backslash? i.e. do you really mean `(".$variable.".EXAMPLE\d+)`

Answer (score 1):

I would use [capture groups](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups):

```
/(.*?)(EXAMPLE\d+)/
```

After the matching operation the line before the word of interest is available in capturing group 1, (`$1`). Like this:

```
$string = "foo bar EXAMPLE1";
$string =~ /(.*?)(EXAMPLE\d+)/;
print($1); # Prints "foo bar "
```

Comment: Thank you! But I need to catch the beginning of the sentence without groups, only with one regex.
The meaning is that I can't use $1 afterwards, I need that the regex will be immediate…

Comment: This is only possible using lookahead assertions and if the word can be expressed as a fixed length pattern. Meaning `word\d` would work, `word\d+` would not work

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.*?` in the beginning.. which means.. match all in a non greedy way (so that it wont eat your following regex)

Something like this:

```
(.*?EXAMPLE\\d+)
```

Comment: @or89 If you will please edit your question to include sample input and expected output, then we will can verify our answers work before we post them.